# IBM DB2 Textsearch SQLSTATE 38H13 / Conflicting process on text search admin function

Tags: db2, full-text-search, db2-luw

Im a using the IBM DB2 Text Search Index (DB2TS) on LUW, latest version. The statements are executed in the IBM Data Studio, latest Version as DB2ADMIN.

From time to time I execute

```
CALL SYSPROC.SYSTS_UPDATE('M2F', 'IX_X3_2DEDEMSJ', '', 'en_US', ?)
```

to update the index.

One Index (of 10) is not updateable. The error codes are SQLCODE=-20426, SQLSTATE=38H13.

It says: A text search management function is in conflict with a pending/running function.

```
CALL SYSPROC.SYSTS_DROP('M2F', 'IX_X3_2DEDEMSJ', '', 'en_US', ?)
```

I tried to DROP the Index -> Same error

I tried to CLEAR the messages events -> Same error

I restartet the database, the DB2TS-service and at least the whole server.

Still the same message. Is there anybody out there who has an idea?

How can I see the pending tasks on an index? Is it possible to cancel tasks by command?

Many thanks :-)
Oliver

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself:

```
CALL SYSPROC.SYSTS_CLEAR_COMMANDLOCKS('M2F', 'IX_X3_2DEDEMSJ', 'en_US', ?)
```

Link to [IBM documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0052000.html)